# How do I plot a scatterplot graph with a repeated-measures variable and a continuous variable in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a four levels repeated measures variable (let's call it RM) and I have a continuous variable predictor (let's call it C).
I want to plot a scatterplot graph with C on the X-Axis and RM on the Y-Axis with different lines within the plot for each level of RM.
Is this possible to do with ggplot or a similar package?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow - this is a relatively basic question, but without some example data and details of what you have tried it's unlikely someone will be able to give you a specific answer.    In general terms, yes, `ggplot2` contains functions that would happily plot your data.  Different lines for each level would be described as a grouping variable.  Check out some basic ggplot2 tutorials and you should have no trouble getting it working.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing ggplot2, you should be able to achieve this type of graphical output. Viewing a portion of your data that you wish to plot would be beneficial to provide a sufficient answer.

I have attached a link to a summary of ggplot2 graphical functions [here](https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/blob/main/data-visualization.pdf). This link provides some background on ggplot2 and the components necessary to create a graph. Three components are needed in ggplot2 to make a graph, the data, the ggplot2 function, and mapping your variables with the aesthetic.

Because you don't have a representation of some of your data, providing a sufficient answer is difficult, but it might look something like this.

ggplot(data=yourdata, aes(x= C(continuous_variable, y = RM(repeated_measures)) +
geom_point()

You may also map geom_line for each RM variable in addition to this example. Hope this helps!

Comment: While I think your example code can be useful, it would be better if you could show it with reproducible data instead of fake objects/data. Otherwise it is difficult for others to try this code out in a real environment without already knowing what you are trying to signify here.

Comment: note a type - you have used `C()` instead of `c()`.   Also, if you wrap your code in back ticks (or use the formatting bar) it will display as code.